# Tracking orders against prepaid account credit

Tags: finance

I have customers with a regular order flow (order, quote, invoice + fulfilment). These orders all go through SAP.
I also have customers who prepay a lump sum as a credit balance and place orders against that credit balance. Only the initial lump sum is recorded in SAP and I use a bunch of spreadsheets to track what they order and how much credit they each have left.

I'm looking for software to replace my bunch of spreadsheets. I know my current system is not good but I don't want to create anything custom before I confirm there is nothing else out there. Ideally it should be web-based SaaS and any price will be cheaper than building something custom.

Comment: Please add your required OS and Price. Also tell us which applications you have tried so far. You could try some real finance software. Most of the popular ones cost quite much but [gnucash](https://gnucash.org/) is free and open source and should be fine if you only use it for a small business. You could just try it, as it is completely free. It works on Linux, Windows and macOS. It also has all the describes functions: order, quote, invoice + fulfillment.

Comment: Ideally web-based SaaS and any price will be cheaper than building something custom.